# JavaScript Object Instantiation from Function not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to pass validated html forms inputs to a constructor function to create a new object and then pass that object to a function. It is not giving me the output.

```js
function validate() {
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  let size = document.getElementById("size").value;
  let liquid1 = document.getElementById("liquid1").value;
  let liquid2 = document.getElementById("liquid2").value;
  let solid1 = document.getElementById("solid1").value;
  let solid2 = document.getElementById("solid2").value;
  let topping1 = document.getElementById("topping1").value;
  let topping2 = document.getElementById("topping2").value;
  let topping3 = document.getElementById("topping3").value;
  if (name == "") {
    alert("Client's name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (phone == "") {
    alert("Client's phone number must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (size == "") {
    alert("Smoothie's size must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (liquid1 == "") {
    alert("Must choose a liquid");
    return false;
  }
  if (liquid2 == "") {
    alert("Must choose another liquid");
    return false;
  }
  if (solid1 == "") {
    alert("Must choose a solid");
    return false;
  }
  if (solid2 == "") {
    alert("Must choose another solid");
    return false;
  }
  if (topping1 == "") {
    alert("Must choose a topping");
    return false;
  }
  if (topping2 == "") {
    alert("Must choose another topping");
    return false;
  }
  if (topping3 == "") {
    alert("Must choose the last topping");
    return false;
  }

  var mySmoothie = new Smoothie(size, [liquid1, liquid2], [solid1, solid2], [topping1, topping2, topping3]);
  mySmoothie.serveIt();
}

var output = document.getElementById('output');

function Smoothie(size, liquids, solids, toppings) {
  this.size = size;
  this.liquids = liquids;
  this.solids = solids;
  this.toppings = toppings;

  this.description = 'A ' + this.size + ' smoothie with ' + this.liquids[0] + ' , ' + this.liquids[1] + ' , ' + this.solids[0] + this.solids[1] + ' , ' + this.toppings[0] + ' , ' + this.toppings[1] + ' , ' + this.toppings[2];
}

Smoothie.prototype.serveIt = function() {
  var cup = document.createElement("img");
  cup.setAttribute('title', this.description);
  cup.setAttribute('src', 'img/smoothie.jpg');
  var cupSize;
  switch (this.size) {
    case 'small':
      cupSize = '100px';
      break;
    case 'medium':
      cupSize = '125px';
      break;
    case 'large':
      cupSize = '150px';
      break;
    default:
      cupSize = '100px';
  }

  cup.setAttribute('height', cupSize);
  output.appendChild(cup);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <label>Client's Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <label>Client's Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone">



  <label>Size of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="size">


  <label>First Liquid of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="liquid1">
  <label>Second Liquid of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="liquid2">

  <label>First Solid of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="solid1">
  <label>Second Solid of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="solid2">

  <label> First Toppings of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="topping1">
  <label>Second Topping of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="topping2">
  <label>Third Topping of Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="topping3">

  <!-- -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>

<p id="output">

</p>
```

it is properly validating the input to make sure they are not blank however I am not receiving the output, I am not sure if I am passing the input to the constructor correctly.

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();validate()">`

Comment: You should call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form submitting behavior, which will navigate away from current page.

Comment: Side note: the correct way is to listen to the form's submit event, not a click of the submit button. You can submit the form by hitting enter.